# loop through the json data from ajax success message google charts

Tags: jquery, ajax, charts, google-visualization

i am trying to pass `json` data from `ajax` success message but `$.each` function is not allowing to display data inside `drawchart()` in google charts. Below is the code that i have tried till now.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['barchart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

var resp_data=JSON.parse(response.msg);
function drawChart() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable({

                  $.each(resp_data, function(key,val){
                  
                  [val.userid, val.ncpu],
                  
                  });
                 });
                         var options = {'title':'test chart',
                       'legend':'right',
                       'width':100000,
                       'height':500,
                        'colors':['blue'],
                     };
                    
        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options)
        }
```

```html
<div id="chart_div" style="overflow:auto;overflow-x:scroll;overflow-y:scroll; "></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

Please help

Comment: @Rohit Batra Thanks for editing.

Comment: is the string generated by `$.each` function correct/valid? try testing that outside of `charts` render function.

Comment: Yes, when i tried outside the function it is printing the values in array format. i tried console.log(val.userid); its printing the values in console.

Comment: Your each contains a callback that is executed asynchronously.

Comment: I dint get exactly. Please suggest answer or edit snippet.

Answer (score 0):

you need to build the data array, prior to calling `arrayToDataTable`

see following snippet...

```
function drawChart() {
  var chartData = [['x', 'y']];  // <-- column headings

  // load data into array
  $.each(resp_data, function (key, val) {
    chartData.push([val.userid, val.ncpu]);
  });

  // convert array to google data table
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);

  var options = {
    title: 'test chart',
    legend: 'right',
    width: 100000,
    height: 500,
    colors: ['blue']
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options)
}
```